# How do I Poison Someone?

Tags: die2nite

This is difficult to ask.  Ok, so this guy is really getting on my nerves.  He's stubborn, obnoxious, idiotic, and completely driving me up the wall.

### It's time for him to go.

However, there is a bit more to it than that.  I could simply organize the other people involved to banish him from our community, but this wouldn't do it for me.  If he is allowed to live he will continue to use up our valuable resources.  **I cannot allow this to happen.**

---

I've come to the conclusion that poison will be the best way to get rid of him, because I could probably get away with it and not be noticed by anyone else.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: For reference, I **am** talking about the game.

Comment: lol who was confused?

Comment: Here's hoping your die2nite handle isn't GnomeSlice and/or your town-mates don't read this site! :)

Comment: I provide regular links to here answering questions brought up in our town.  I don't really care.  Maybe I should just poison myself, and get it over with.

Comment: I'm sure some NSA agent got a kick out of this post when all the government filters for possible terrorist chatter lit up

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only way to actually poison someone is to take a Vial of Poison, combine it with a water ration, food, or a drug, and then get that person to drink the ration.

A Vial of Poison is created using Corrosive Liquid, a Battery and Pharmaceutical Products. You can then combine this with water, food or drugs to make a poisoned item. This will look completely similar to a normal item, except it will not stack with the normal items. Meaning if you have a water ration in the bank, and you deposit a poisoned water ration in the bank, you see two identical icons in the bank, and you can not know which is which.

It's not that easy to do, really. It's easier to get the town to banish him.

Comment: Especially now that Gallows have been implemented...

Comment: But I'd rather not waste his ap by banishing him, or resources by building a gallows.

Comment: @Gnome You don't want to waste his AP by banishing him, but killing him is OK?

Answer (score 5):

If the person keeps food/water/drugs in their chest (and assuming you can create the posion), a good way to do it is to steal the thing that is in their chest.  Poison it, then mail it back to them, saying that you were just stealing it to get the distinction.  Then you have to wait for them to actually use it.  This is much more likely to happen if they are banished and don't have access to food/water/drugs from the bank.

Comment: Or I could just throw it in the well and spin the roulette.

Comment: You can't put poisoned stuff in the well.  You could put it in the bank, but not only will that possibly kill a random person, if there is anything non-poisoned there it will be very obvious, and will likely be traced back to you as well.

Comment: It shows up in the bank as "poisoned water" ?

Comment: No, it shows up as water.  But it appears in a different stack than any other water in the bank.  So anyone who knows the game will know immediately what that means.  If you're going to put something poisoned in the bank, you want it to be the only one of its kind of item.