# How do I murder my fellow citizens?

Tags: die2nite

Is there any other way to kill other Citizens besides:

- Shunning + Hanging
- Poisoning
- Closing the Gates on them

There is one particularly annoying guy that I want to kill, but I alone can't kill him with these methods.

Comment: Without reading the tag on this question, it's quite... random, off-topic, and concerning!

Comment: title should be reworded to "How do I commit murder"

Comment: Sorry about that! Title reworded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by poisoning him, but you can attack someone if you're in 100 SP towns for a cost of 3 AP with about a 1/3 chance of wounding them. It's not that useful, but I think that it's the only other way.

You should be aware that your town will not likely be happy with this, and that shunning is probably the best way...

Comment: If you want to read up, [we do teach the fine art of poisoning people](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14814/how-do-i-poison-someone) ♪

Comment: Thank you! Shunning is not really and option since we don't have Rusty Chain, but the attack info is good, thank you!

Comment: Oops, meant to write a paragraph, not to add the comment!
@Grace Note: Yes, I read that, but me making the poison would certainly rise a warning thread, so no could do.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the three basic ways.  You either have to have them die immediately as a result of hanging, poison, or cyanide, or you have to have them be outside during the attack.  It is not intended to be easy for a single player to kill another they dislike.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can eat certain items to become a ghoul, and then you devour the citizen. It's actaully very easy, but if you do not keep it secret or you devour someone in the town, the town could discover you and kill you.   Go here to find out more- http://die2nitewiki.com/wiki/Ghoul